# Visualizing speed and acceleration of typing (smartphone keyboard)

Tags: data-visualization, heatmap

I have a dataset of smartphone keyboard recordings. Each sample consists of the pressed key on the keyboard (e.g. 'a') and the timestamp. From this data I can compute the speed of typing (speed between two pressed keys) and the acceleration of typing. Now, I would like to visualize this data. Unfortunately, a heat map is probably not working because for speed at least two keys on the keyboard must be considered and for acceleration at leaset three keys need to be considered.

Any ideas how speed and acceleration on a keyboard could be visualized

Comment: How is your data? Do you have a sample of different users and want to compare each user ?? Do you have a sample of different keyboards? I don't really get what you want to compare in a plot. Can you give sample data ??